# Use parent scope variable in angular and javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, variables

i have this javascript code:

```
myApp.factory('Reddit', function($http) {
  var Reddit = function() {
    this.items = [];
    this.busy = false;
    this.after = '';
  };

  Reddit.prototype.nextPage = function() {
    console.log(this.items);// []
    $http({method: 'GET', url: url}).
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      console.log(this.items); // undefined ?? how to access to items list
    })
```

How can access to items list in `success` function?

Comment: `this` in success callback refers to the callback function, not `Reddit` object, therefore `this.items` is undefined. See @ogc-nick's answer on how to avoid this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try assigning it to a local variable while it is defined. That local variable should be defined in your success function.

```
Reddit.prototype.nextPage = function() {
    console.log(this.items);// []
    var localItems = this.items; // if it is defined here, then alias it to a local var ( you can rename it to whatever)
    $http({method: 'GET', url: url}).
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      console.log(this.items); // undefined ?? how to access to items list
      console.log(localItems); // should work
    })
```

I assume though that you are going to want access to the whole object in which case you can just alias `this`

```
Reddit.prototype.nextPage = function() {
    var obj = this;
    $http({method: 'GET', url: url}).
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      obj.items.push('xxx');
    });
```

Here is a plunkr that shows multiple instances of a `Reddit` object building distinct `items` lists: [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/nEjm9TdRs0MMwhTsG3SG). Make sure to check the console.